# ASP.NET MVC2 Apps - Extending App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Here is my problem for using mvc2, I cant find a silver bullet fix for this.

I have a standard mvc app which has following views, controllers and Models

View
WorkOrders
Estimates

Model
WorkOrder
Estimate

Controller
WorkOrderController
EstimateController

---

I recently got a client who wants this app with little customization. I am still adding new modules to this app so I dont want to clone my app and customize because then I have to maintain two code bases. Upgrading any modules in base app as well as app that I cloned.

So here is how my Client App will look like

View
ClientWorkOrders
Estimates

Model
WorkOrder
Estimate

Controller
ClientWorkOrderController
EstimateController

Now If I want to add invoice I have to add it at both apps. Any easier way to handle this in microsoft mvc.

Comment: This will very much depend on what this application is doing, how is functionality organized and what is the required new functionality. Stating just the MVC names is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing much about the application -- you could turn to the provider model (depending how much additional functionality they need) or you could implement a plugin framework. Both options could be a huge architecture change.

I've never used it, but the [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) framework was specifically designed for creating plugin architectures.